# How to get $id to delete in list item?

Tags: database, wordpress

I create a function `list_product` show list product.

I want to have a button `delete` on each product on list products.

But I can't get `$id` to delete.

Have any method to delete a rows on list database?

My function look like:

```
<?php

function product_list() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "product";
        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = %s", $id));
        } else {
            $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,name from $table_name");
        }
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=product_update&id=' . $row->id); ?>">Cập nhật</a></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' name="delete" value='Delete' class='button' onclick="return confirm('&iquest; Confirm Delete?')"></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the $_GET variables instead of the $_POST variables. $_GET['id']

Comment: instead of $row->id write $row->ID

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a PHP expert but I think here is what is going on.
You are not sending the `$id` variable anywhere. Also, there isn't any form in your code. Since you aren't using an JS submission, there isn't any submission.

Try the following code.

```
<?php

function product_list() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "product";
        if(isset($_POST['row_id'])){
            $id = $_POST['row_id'];
            $id = $id[0];
        }else{
            $id = '';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = %s", $id));
        } else {
            $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,name from $table_name");
        }
        ?>
<form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=product_update&id=' . $row->id); ?>">Cập nhật</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="row_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
                        <input type='submit' name="delete" value='Delete' class='button' onclick="return confirm('&iquest; Confirm Delete?')">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
</form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```